# Encryption of password

Tags: encryption, openfire

i just wanna ask what does the openfire use to encrypt passowrd? md5? or wat? =)

Comment: just as a side note... MD5 is NOT an encryption algotithm, it's a hasing algorithm

Comment: I just have to thank you for your comment. This needs to be a public service announcement I think...

Answer (score 8):

[Blowfish](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/openfire/auth/AuthFactory.html#encryptPassword(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 1):

Openfire supports multiple storage types so it actually supports a couple hashing algorithms. It depends on the storage type and configuration in openfire.xml

Usually found in: /opt/openfire/config/openfire.xml

Looks something like <passwordType>sha1</passwordType>

Your question is a bit ambiguous though. As it could also mean the format the password is sent over XMPP from the client. This depends on the authentication protocol used and will be defined in the XMPP specs...